# Wxpython ScrollBar

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, listctrl

I want that the ScrollBar of the my wx.ListCtrl, will get down automatically when a new item is added to the list and the ScrollBar becomes longer.
This is how I create a wx.ListCtrl

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title='2', pos=(0, 0), size=(500, 500))
frame.Show(True)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
message_list = wx.ListCtrl(frame, size=(200, 200), pos=(0, 0),
                       style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
message_list.InsertColumn(0, 'Chat: ', width=150)
for i in range(15):
   message_list.InsertItem(i, "name" + str(i))

### I want that after this loop, the scroll bar will be at the end of the list (Name 14)

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Select(self, idx, on=1)
>   Selects/deselects an item.
>   & `EnsureVisible(n)` makes sure that the selected item is visible i.e. it scrolls the list control.

So this will work:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title='2', pos=(0, 0), size=(500, 500))
frame.Show(True)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
message_list = wx.ListCtrl(frame, size=(200, 200), pos=(0, 0),
                            style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
message_list.InsertColumn(0, 'Chat: ', width=150)
for i in range(30):
    message_list.InsertItem(i, "name" + str(i))

msg_endpoint = message_list.GetItemCount() - 1
message_list.Select(msg_endpoint,1)    #Select last item
message_list.EnsureVisible(msg_endpoint)
### I want that after this loop, the scroll bar will be at the end of the list (Name 14)

app.MainLoop()
```

Note: Use `message_list.Select(i,0)` to De-select item(i)
The scrollbar only becomes visible when required.

[image]

Comment: I Tried it and it didn't work. The ScrollBar still stayed at the top of the list.

Comment: My mistake, I misread the question, totally missing the Scrollbar part of it. I assumed you wanted item selection for some reason. Must have been a brain burp! The edited answer should at least address the issue, if not answer it to your satisfaction.